# Permanent outgoing SSH tunnel with TomatoUSB

Tags: ssh-tunnel, tomato

I use SSH tunnel(s) from computers in my home to a remote server, in order to have secure connections and appear to be where I'm not (I live in Europe but want to access Netflix for example).

The problem, is that this has to be set on every computer / device (on Android devices I use SSHTunnel which works perfectly, but requires rooting).

I would like to have an SSH tunnel at the router level, where all communications from that router to the outside world would use the tunnel.

How do I do that? I have an ASUS RT-N66u with Tomato USB installed.

When trying to google the answer the only tutorials I can find are about how to setup an SSH tunnel TO the router FROM the outside world (TO your home FROM your office for instance).

What I want is have all communications emanating from my LAN through the router, to use an SSH tunnel to a remote server.

Comment: Have you considered using OpenVPN instead of SSH tunneling?  SSH is not very efficient for tunneling and there are several versions of Tomato USB that have OpenVPN built in.

Comment: What's good about SSH tunneling is that it requires zero configuration on the target machine; I can spin up a server anywhere in the world and be able to SSH to it right away.

Comment: @heavyd Do you have an example of this being set up and working?  I've tried setting up OpenVPN and none of it makes any sense and nothing works.  SSH tunneling is very easy to set up and works fine.

Comment: @endolith, I have it working on my home network using one of the [Shibby mods](http://tomato.groov.pl/) (I use the Big-VPN build on my N16).  Shibby's build has a link to the [OpenVPN docs](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki) as well which are very helpful when generating keys.